# Does template matching works if the template is not from the original image?

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection

I've seen a lot of tutorials in Youtube about template matching in opencv-python, one thing they have in common is that they always uses the source image when matching the template. My question is does template matching works if the template is not from the original image? Can I use it as a simple method for object detection? And how accurate it will be? thanks

Comment: present your problem. the question is quite vague. -- template matching **does not require** the template to be from the original image.

Answer (score 0):

Template matching is a technique in digital image processing for finding small parts of an image which match a template image.

This technique only works in the images that are almost the same. Small changes on the desired objects included in new frames can create difficulties to make a good match.

To detect an object(template) in an image you could use local feature descriptors and match the descriptors of every keypoint to detect if a zone has a high number of matches to assign them to the object.

Hope it works.